# My tester is going to the wrong constructor

Tags: java

I am new to programming so if i ask a question that can be easily fixed, please forgive me. My program has a tester class with a main. When i send that to my RegularPolygon class, it sends it to the wrong constructor. I have two constructors. 1 without perameters

```
public RegularPolygon()
    {
       myNumSides = 5;
       mySideLength = 30;
    }//end default constructor
```

and my second, with perameters.

```
public RegularPolygon(int numSides, double sideLength)
    {
        myNumSides = numSides;
        mySideLength = sideLength;
    }// end constructor
```

in my tester class i have these two lines:

```
RegularPolygon shape = new RegularPolygon(numSides, sideLength);
        shape.menu();
```

numSides and sideLength were declared and initialized earlier in the testing class.

So what i want to happen, is the tester class sends numSides and sideLength to the second constructor and use it in that class. But it only uses the default constructor, which therefor ruins the whole rest of the program. Can somebody help me?

For those of you who want to see more of my code: here you go

```
public double vertexAngle()
    {
        System.out.println("The vertex angle method: " + myNumSides);// prints out 5
        System.out.println("The vertex angle method: " + mySideLength); // prints out 30

        double vertexAngle;
        vertexAngle = ((myNumSides - 2.0) / myNumSides) * 180.0;
        return vertexAngle;
    }//end method vertexAngle

public void menu()
{
    System.out.println(myNumSides); // prints out what the user puts in
    System.out.println(mySideLength); // prints out what the user puts in
    goToGraphic();
    calcR(myNumSides, mySideLength);
    calcr(myNumSides, mySideLength);
    print(); 
}// end menu
```

This is my entire tester class:

```
public static void main(String[] arg)
{
    int numSides;
    double sideLength;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Regular Polygon Program!");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Enter the number of sides of the polygon ==> ");
    numSides = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Enter the side length of each side ==> ");
    sideLength = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println();

    RegularPolygon shape = new RegularPolygon(numSides, sideLength);
    shape.menu();
}//end main
```

For testing it i sent it numSides 4 and sideLength 100.

Comment: It most definitely won't send it to the first constructor if you are really using `new RegularPolygon(numSides, sideLength);`.

Comment: Yes why do you think it does go to the good one ? can you give all the class code maybe you made a mistake somewhere else.

Comment: What are you doing that makes you so sure the first constructor is being used?  Why don't you add a debugger to step through it, or do `System.out.println("constructor A");` in your constructors...

Comment: are you sure you aren't just passing it 5 and 30?

Comment: What is suppossed to happen, is the user enters the number of sides and the side length. Then the program prints out a picture of that polygon. But no matter how many sides i say it has, it always shows a pentagon.

Comment: The problem is not in the code you posted. It's elsewhere. Use your debugger, and if you're stuck, post the rest of the polygon class and of the code displaying it.

Comment: that's not an issue with your constructor it must be somewhere else in your code where you actually draw the polygon

Comment: One of my methods in class RegularPolygon is vertexAngle();  I used two lines to find out which constructor it is using. I typed in System.out.println(myNumSides); and System.out.println(mySideLength); When those lines print out, it prints 5 and 30.

Comment: Stop posting comments and start updating your question to include the code where you're actually showing us what values you're sending, a long with lots of other relevant code that makes you so sure that the wrong constructor is called.

Comment: Just add a `System.out.println("blub");` into your constructor and you will see which one is called...

Comment: What values are in `numSides` and `sideLength` in the test class when you use them to call the constructor?

Comment: I updated my post so that it shows the whole tester class and says what values i used. @nhgrif

Comment: So, the printed values in menu() are the ones entered by the user. So the correct constructor is called. You didn't show how the vertexAngle() method is called. The problem is, once again, in the code that you don't show.

Comment: I simply had a System.out.println(vertexAngle()); line to print out the vertex angle. I didnt realize that it would be important to put that up. @JBNizet

Comment: So... what exactly is displaying wrong?  The first two lines in `menu()` print the user inputted values, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
public RegularPolygon() {
   System.out.println("Default constructor called.");
   myNumSides = 5;
   mySideLength = 30;
}//end default constructor

public RegularPolygon(int numSides, double sideLength) {
    System.out.println("Two-argument constructor called.");
    System.out.println("numSides = " + numSides + ", sideLength = " + sideLength);
    myNumSides = numSides;
    mySideLength = sideLength;
}// end constructor
```

So, there's one form of debugging to clear any doubt about what constructor is being called and what the values of `numSides` and `sideLength` should be being initialized to.  You can follow this debugging pattern in any other methods to verify that, Yes, this is indeed the method being called, and Yes, the values this method is using are indeed the values I intend it to use.

In your tester class, I'd do something like this:

```
System.out.println("numSides = " + numSides + ", sideLength = " + sideLength);
System.out.println("Instantiating RegularPolygon with numSides & sideLength");
RegularPolygon shape = new RegularPolygon(numSides, sideLength);
```

This is all just debugging 101.  But the point here is that you're making the assumption that your code is behaving unexpectedly because of Culprit A, but realistically, there are several different things that could cause the problem.  You're convinced that the wrong constructor is being called, so these code snippets will give you some evidence as to what's happening.  It could be that the wrong constructor is being called, or it could be that the right constructor is being called but with the wrong arguments.

Either way, we'd need to see more of the code from your tester class to see what might be the cause, because the code you've provided in your answer would absolutely result in the two-argument constructor being called... but you don't tell us what values you're passing it.

Comment: Thank you, I realized my problem was in the vertexAngle() method. I changed it to vertexAngle(int numSides, double sideLength) and then called it with those perameters. It now works perfectly. Thank you for the debugging help as well